# AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. [.NET Core 3.1]

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

I've build a WebAPI .NET Core 3.1 using AutoMapper v10.0 and AutoMapper Dependency Injection 8.0.1 and I'm encountering the following error

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Role -> RoleResources
Entity.Models.Role -> Entity.Resources.RoleResources
lambda_method(Closure , Role , RoleResources , ResolutionContext )

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ICollection`1 -> ICollection`1
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Entity.Models.Role, Entity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Entity.Resources.RoleResources, Entity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
lambda_method(Closure , ICollection<Role> , ICollection<RoleResources> , ResolutionContext )
```

I've tired to use .ReverseMap(), Mapthe ICollection directly in the profile with no luck.

Here is my classes

> Role.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Entity.Models
{
    [Table("Role")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RoleNumber { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RolePrivilage> RolePrivilages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> RoleResources.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Entity.Resources
{
    public class RoleResources
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int RoleNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Startup.cs Configure method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<WhiteLandsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
    services.AddScoped<IPrivilageService, PrivilageService>();

    services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IPrivilageRepository, PrivilageRepository>();
}
```

> Mapping Profile

```
using AutoMapper;
using Entity.Models;
using Entity.Resources;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Core.Mapping
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            //CreateMap<ICollection<Role>, ICollection<RoleResources>>();
            CreateMap<Role, RoleResources>();
        }
    }
}
```

> RoleController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ICollection<RoleResources>> Get()
{
    var roles = await _roleService.List();
    var resources = _mapper.Map<ICollection<Role>, ICollection<RoleResources>>(roles);
    return resources;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please register your automapper in configuration service like below and give it a try ?

```
   services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Comment: Why would you consider only loaded assemblies? What if some needed assembly is not already loaded?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - that's a valid point , but if assemblies are to be loaded dynamically then how would a mapping profile be created then in that case we are more likely to get the error - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: Exactly :) Of course just because there is a profile somewhere, it doesn't mean that assembly is loaded. That's the problem with your answer.

Comment: @AdityaSingh I was about to post the fix to this problem. I was able to fix it by adding the profiler in the startup. 

services.AddAutoMapper(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>(), typeof(Startup));

Additionally, your fix also worked when I tried it on other solution.

Comment: @NasserX-Thanks for the update, this is helpful and informative